# Extracting Javascript Object parameters using preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to extract the video information to be processed after from a JS object:

```
var playerSettings = {flashplayer: "jwplayer.flash.swf",width: 640,height: 480,
skin: "five.xml",primary: "flash",autostart: "true",abouttext: "this video",aboutlink: "www.video.com",startparam: "ec_seek",
playlist: [{sources: [{ type: "mp4", file: "http://video-media.com/T/4/I/N/T4INzPOLNGF.480.mp4?2a8283553d5cb07b981d3deae8444eb54ae8832fd5c37be54baba4c6d41e2fb5f374d06c9f5d7609a96b96ab5fec4fd487af4cde9304969fce3913c656adb1960d3c6f7ffb87649b34d8a0a87a14b2b1243663709429bdfae86a3e9521bf631393b37c2eb2c42f1e654dbeec41579aaf3f3b8075e318&150"}],"previewer.file" : "http://i-sec.video-media.com/T/4/I/N/T4INzPOLNGF-sprite.jpg"}],
plugins: {"js/videopreviewer-2.0.js": {frameWidth: "156",frameHeight: "117",columns: "1",rows: "50",
totalFrames: 50,loadOnStart: true,thumbnailsOffset: 2,tooltip: {hook: false,cornerRadius: 10,padding: 5,paddingTop: 0,paddingBottom: 6,color: "#CCCCCC"}}}};
```

I am trying to get

```
{ type: "mp4", file: "http://video-media.com/T/4/I/N/T4INzPOLNGF.480.mp4?2a8283553d5cb07b981d3deae8444eb54ae8832fd5c37be54baba4c6d41e2fb5f374d06c9f5d7609a96b96ab5fec4fd487af4cde9304969fce3913c656adb1960d3c6f7ffb87649b34d8a0a87a14b2b1243663709429bdfae86a3e9521bf631393b37c2eb2c42f1e654dbeec41579aaf3f3b8075e318&150"}
```

from the above setting

What I have tried is this:

```
preg_match_all('/sources: \[^(.*)&\]/', $scriptText, $match);
var_dump($match);
```

But it gives empty array.

Comment: Could you use http://php.net/json_decode instead? :shrug:

Comment: @KevinM1, I think PHP does not recognise JS string.

Comment: if you insist on using regex, remove ^ (match start of line) and & (match ampersand)

Comment: @KevinM1, Are you suggesting using `str_replace` to remove JS specific constructs?

Comment: @KevinM1, json_decode is not working.

Comment: `json_decode` won't work, because that isn't JSON. The object keys aren't quoted.

Comment: @lonesomeday, Yeah any way to quote them?

Comment: @mrN You mean adding them in before doing `json_decode`? Well, it's *possible*, but I doubt there's a simple way to do it.

Comment: @lonesomeday, So the suggested `json_decode` method does not seem to be good solution for this problem? Correct?

Comment: @mrN Correct. Javascript objects are not the same as JSON (contrary to popular belief).

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure if PHP would care if the keys were quoted.  Which is why I made it a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insist on using regex, try it without ^ (match start of line) and & (match ampersand):

```
preg_match_all('/sources: \[(.*)\]/', $scriptText, $match);
```

Also,

```
(.*)
```

is greedy, so you may get more than you bargained for.

```
(.*?)
```

will actually stop at the first ] which is what you probably intended.  I also like

```
([^\]]*)
```

for this - greedy match for any character except "]" - can be more readable.